# Obtener todos los resultados de las tablas, incluso los que no están unidos

Tags: mysql

Necesito ayuda con la siguiente consulta en MySQL, tengo 3 tablas:

**app**:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| id_app  (PK) | name      |
+--------------+-----------+
| 1            | Facebook  |
| 2            | Instagram |
+--------------+-----------+
```

**lang**:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| id_lang (PK) | value     |
+--------------+-----------+
| 1            | English   |
| 2            | Español   |
+--------------+-----------+
```

**app_lang**:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| id_app  (PK) | id_lang (PK) |
+--------------+-------------+
| 1            | 1           |
| 2            | 1           |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo reviso la app (tengo la `id_app`) me traiga todos los idiomas aunque no estén asociados en la tabla **app_lang** a la `id_app` correspondiente

**Resultado**:

```
+----------+----------------------+---------+
| id_app   | id_lang | name       | value   | 
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1        | 1       | Facebook   | English |
| NULL     | 2       | NULL       | Español |
+---------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: No entiendo. ¿En `app_lang` **tienes dos columnas con el mismo nombre: `id_app`**? Eso está muyyy raro. ¿Podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano acabo de reparar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes usar `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a.id_app,
        l.id_lang,
        a.name,
        l.value
FROM lang l
LEFT JOIN app_lang al
    ON l.id_lang = al.id_lang
LEFT JOIN app a
    ON al.id_app = a.id_app
    AND a.id_app = 1
;
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias :)